# Mouse's forward and back buttons don't work

Tags: 10.10, xorg, mouse, input-devices

I have two buttons on my mouse to go forwards and back:

[image]

- They used to work all right in Firefox, but now they don't any more. I've since switched to Google Chrome (the package from [google.com/chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/), not chromium).
- I haven't changed any configuration to do with input devices in the mean time.
- `xev` doesn't seem to recognize the buttons. The others work well. Even the weird zoom-slider on this mouse is recognized by xev. It's only the forwards and back buttons that don't do anything.

How do I get them to work?

The mouse is a Logitech VX Revolution in case that's important.

**Edit at Dec. 10th, 11pm:**

The back button has just started working, after an update. I'm confused. :P

The forwards button still doesn't work. `xev` recognizes the back button now, not the other one.

Comment: Sounds like a regression... do you know about what date it stopped working?

Comment: @maco I don't, sorry to say. I'd just be making things up if I start to guess. If you could give me a package hint, I could rummage through the apt-logs to see what has changed when.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mouse is just broken. I've tested it on another machine, doesn't work either. I've since bought a new one, works perfectly.

The thing not working in `xev` should've been a good clue.

Comment: Could you please show me your xorg.conf file? I feel there's something wrong with mine, I have two Logitech mice, one of them is a g9 which was set-up first and works fine, the other is the VX revolution. The VX rev is the one whose buttons don't work properly...